# A frog from k lilypad either jumps to k+1 or k+2 lilypad. Find the probability that it reaches pad 7 if it is initially at pad 1.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Lilypads numbered $1,2,3,\cdots$ lie in a row in a pond. A frog is initially on pad $1$. From any pad $k$, the frog will jump to either pad number $k+1$ or $k+2$ with equal probability of ${1\over 2}$. The probability that the frog visits pad $7$ is ${m\over n}$ where ($m,n$) = $1$, Evaluate $n-m$.

Well I wanted to know as to how to attack this problem. I mean Probability = Number of favorable outcomes / Total Outcomes. What is the total outcomes here ?? What are the favorable outcomes ?? How to count them ??

Comment: I suggest working recursively.  A good path to $7$ must either be a good path to $6$ followed by one, or a good path to $5$ followed by two.  And so on..  If needs be, you can simply enumerate all the good paths that way.

Comment: You have a simple recursive relation of $P(K), P(K-1), P(K-2)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be wrong. It's happened before (once).

$P($ reaches pad $7)$ = $1 - P(6 \to 8 \ | $ reaches pad $6)$

$\color{red}{= 1 - \frac12P(\text{ reaches pad 6 })}$ [because assuming it reaches pad $6,$ it has $\frac12$ chance of landing on $8$.]

$= 1 - \frac12(\ 1 - P(5\to7\ |$ reaches pad $5)\ )$

$\color{red}{ = 1 - \frac12(\ 1 - \frac12 P( \text{reaches pad } 5)\ )}$

$= 1 - \frac12(\ 1 - \frac12(\ 1 - P(4 \to 6|$ reaches pad $4\ )\ )\ )$

$\color{red}{= 1 - \frac12(\ 1 - \frac12(\ 1 - \frac12P(\text{reaches pad 4})\ )\ )}$

$ = ...$

$ \color{red}{= 1 - \frac12\left(\ 1 - \frac12\left(\ 1 - \frac12\left(\ 1 - \frac12\left(\ 1 - \frac12\left(\ 1 - \frac12P\left(\text{reaches pad 1}\ \right)\ \right)\ \right)\ \right)\ \right)\ \right)}$

$ = 1 - \frac12\left(\ 1 - \frac12\left(\ 1 - \frac12\left(\ 1 - \frac12\left(\ 1 - \frac12\left(\ 1 - \frac12 \times 1\ \right)\ \right)\ \right)\ \right)\ \right) $

$ = \frac{43}{64}$.

Since $(n,m) = (64,43) = 1,\ n - m = 64 - 43 = 21.$

Comment: This would agree with David Quinn's method if David Quinn had done it right.

Comment: Also the same answer as jlammy, the Markov Chain guy.

Answer (score 1):

We can enumerate the number of pads the frog leaps over to get to pad 7:

Case 1$$1+1+1+1+1+1$$
1 permutation, $p=(\frac{1}{2})^6$

Case 2
$$1+1+1+1+2$$
5 permutations, $p=5\times(\frac{1}{2})^5$

Case 3
$$1+1+2+2$$

6 permutations, $p=6\times(\frac{1}{2})^4$

Case 4
$$2+2+2$$

1 permutations, $p=(\frac{1}{2})^3$

Total $=\frac{43}{64}$

Comment: Case 4 should be $p=4\times(\frac12)^4$, I think.

Comment: More importantly, the total distance from pad $1$ to pad $7$ is $6$, not $7$...

Comment: Thanks @TonyK I will fix it

Answer (score 1):

It might help to model the process as a Markov Chain (though this isn't necessary).

Let $p_n$ be the probability that the frog hits lilypad $n$. Then $p_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}\right)$, and $p_1=1$, $p_2=\frac{1}{2}$. At this point, you can either pump the recursion for $n=7$, or solve the relation to get $p_n=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$. Either way, you get $p_7=\frac{43}{64}$.